# What is an HDD optical driver caddy made of?

Tags: hard-drive, optical-drive

I want to use a second HDD in place of my optical drive, but I don't have a caddy in my country. What are these made up from? Maybe I can make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one in my Lenovo that I have an SSD in is a combination of a light aluminum and plastic (abs it appears).  To do it, you would probably need a converter from microSata to Sata, depending on what drive you would want in here.

Here is a [link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0058AH2US) for you to look at the idea.